# copy all files and folder inside a dir except .jpg and .png files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, copy, subdirectory

Folder Structure:

```
rootfoder:
    subfoler1:
        image.jpg
    subfoler2:
        image.png
        text.txt
    subfoler3
```

I have to copy all the files/folder inside root folder to des folder.
But .jpg and .png file should be not copied and empty folder should also be copied.

Can this be done in python using any lib?

Comment: Yes. This can be done. `os.listdir` can be used to find files/directories, and `shutil.copy` (and several others) can be used for copying.

Comment: can you provide a code for it. I used both and i am not able to exclude the .jpg and .png file and copy the empty dir at the same time.

Comment: I cannot provide any code advice, since you program is not specific enough. You should have provided a skeleton of your code, and then there would have been an opportunity to suggest modifications to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shutil for this:

```
import shutil

shutil.copytree('/tmp/source', '/tmp/target' , ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns('*.jpg', '*.png'))
```

shutil provides an ignore_patterns function to skip certain files on tree copying.

HTH,
ferdy

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a 'honorable mention', even if I second ferdy on using shutil:

```
from dirsync import sync
sync("./Frog", "./Throat", action="sync", ignore=[".*py",".*jpg"], create=True)
```

from https://github.com/tkhyn/dirsync

It seems to have been written as a command line utility alternative to rsync and adds the option to storing a config file, but it is callable from python and does the job.